# How should I setup Shipping and Receiving tables for RDBMS?

Tags: ms-access, rdbms

Ok, so I am a student, and have VERY limited experience with databases, but I am trying to build the tables for a Shipping company for an assignment. Currently I have The following 10 tables [with attributes] (it will not allow me to post an image):

```
Table1 
======
Customer[PK - CustId, CustAddressId(FK from table "Address"), CustBusName,....], 

Table2 
======
PU_Man [PK - PUManId, PUDate, PUComments, PUPackageId (FK from table "Package"), 
PUCustId (FK from table "Customer"), PUDTID (FK from table DriverTruckRef)]

Table3 
======
Del_Man [PK - DelManId, DelDate, DelComments, 
DelPackageId (FK from table "Package"), 
DelCustId (FK from table "Customer"), 
DelDTId (FK from table DriverTruckRef)]

Table4 
======
Truck [PK - TruckVin#, TimeLoggedOut, .....], 

Table5 
======
Driver [PK - DriverId, DriverFN, DriverLN, 
DriverRoute# (FK from table "Route"),....]

Table6 
======
DriverTruckRef [PK - DTId, DriverId (FK from table "Driver")]

Table7 
======
Address [PK - AddressId, 
AddressCustId (FK from Customer table), 
Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip]

Table8 
======
Package [PK - PackageId, PackagePUCondition, 
PackagePUProblems, PackageDelCondition, PackageDelProblems]

Table9
======
Route [PK - RouteId, AddressId (FFK from table "Address")]

Table10
=======
Payment [PK - PaymentId, 
PaymentCustomerId (FK from customer table), 
PaymentPackageId (FK from "Package" table), 
PaymentType, PaymentInfo, PaymentAmt, 
PaymentAddressId (FK from table "Address")]
```

I know this is probably the easiest scenario out there for anyone who is experienced, but I am hoping someone can just rip this piece to shreds so that I can see the big picture. Before the shredding of my pride begins, I know the 1:1/n:m/1:m/etc relationships are incorrect, but I need a visual representation of the tables, and Access is what I had to go with. The PK/FK is more the focus.

Also, I am thinking maybe I need to break down the Payment table as well.

Any criticism and advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try again? There's absolutely nothing here to make this question even remotely answerable. :) I believe you need a certain amount of rep to upload images (as a spam prevention measure), so you'll have to do it all in the text. Edit your post to provide the additional details - click the edit link near the tags.

Comment: Thank you Ken. I realized that after the post was added. It did not warn me :(

Comment: Would be so much easier if I could just show you the image. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Randy, try once again. :) You need to format your new text so that it's readable, and so it makes sense. Indent code by four or more spaces (for proper indentation), or use the `{}` button on the toolbar. You can also press `Ctrl+K` with a block of text selected. Preview what you've entered (realtime before posting) by looking at the area directly below the edit box, so you can make adjustments to the appearance. I have no idea what your edit just provided - it's a jumbled mass of noise. I would edit to try and help, if I knew what it was you posted. :)

Comment: It's a much better attempt. :) I'll see if I can clean it up some. Don't be surprised if this gets closed, though... It's not a good question based on the lack of overall information, and because it's typical to post the actual DDL for the tables instead of just vague descriptions as you have above. Hopefully, someone can understand the point of your question and help; I'm afraid I've done all I can. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will get you started - every line is a table and the table details are omitted, focusing on keys

```
Customer
Customer*-Addresses*
Addresses
Packages
Destinations[Addresses,Packages]

DeliveryLog[Package,Driver,Route]
DeliveryAttemptLog[...]


Trucks
Trucks*-Drivers*
Drivers

Hubs
Hubs*-Trucks*
Hubs*-Drivers*
Locations[Packages,Hubs]
Loadings[Packages,Trucks]


Routes
Routes*-Addresses*

Packages*-Routes*
```

It can get pretty complicated depending on the flexibility you want.

Comment: That is my problem with the assignment, is that it seems to be pretty arbitrary. No idea how technical he wants me to be. Thank you for the information. What is the purpose of the PackagesRoutesRef?

Comment: You may have overlapping routes, so a package can be assigned to many (potential) routes before the load-on-truck event. And perhaps your instructor is intentionally giving an open-ended problem to see how well you can flesh out all potentialities.

Comment: Also, you have to think about there being a whole scheduling/assignment system laid on top of things. So you would have a 'typical routes' table, and a mechanism to decide what routes you will be running (that day) and a way to assign routes. In general, you have to think about time, which is a bitch.

Comment: Those just come down to the algorithms, which is what we are about to get to I think. Let the headache begin:) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, thinking about what I wrote, there are a few assumptions that are a no-go... like 'all trucks are of an infinite size', and 'routes are standardized and not dynamically computed'. Like I was saying, its compie-kated.

Comment: Not to mention packing order and refrigeration :)